# Does someone has an example of Docker Rails configuation for AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker

I Have been using OpsWorks with custom cookbooks, it works ok, but i have lately been reading about Docker and seems very interesting, mostly because of the resource optimisation.

So i'm looking for a blog post that could guide me thought the process of setting this up using docker on AWS

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with AWS. But to get docker running follow:

https://docs.docker.com/installation/amazon/

> Step 8: Once connected to the instance, type sudo yum install -y docker ; sudo service docker start to install and start Docker

As soon as you have docker running you can look at this docker example repo:

https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-rails-dev-demo/

> This is a demo app I created show how to develop and deploy a moderately complex application with docker.
>
> See the Dockerfile for comments on the setup.

You can also give http://devchat.tv/ruby-rogues/161-rr-docker-deploys-with-sam-saffron a listen. [Sam and discourse for that matter are using docker and everything is open-source.](https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker).

But this is some fairly advanced stuff. So for starters check out the docker-rails-dev-demo and read the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/) or the [dockerbook](http://www.dockerbook.com/).